# How can I get the Plasma 5 Device Notifier to give me appropriate options for DVDs after upgrading from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dvd, plasma-5

Previous to installing Kubuntu 15.04, I was using Kubuntu 14.10 with Plasma 4.
There, the Device Notifier would give me a number of options for Video Discs which I inserted. These included playing the DVD with VLC and playing it with Dragon Player.

Now with Plasma 5 in Kubuntu 15.04, I only get the option to 'Open with File Manager' even though I still have VLC and Dragon Player installed:

[image: Device Notifier, showing only the option to open DVDs with a File Manager]

This isn't very useful if I actually want to watch the DVD.
I can work around it by mounting the device, then opening VLC, navigating to the mount location and playing it using 'Open Disc...', but this seems silly given that it was so simple to use before.

I have found the 'Device Actions' configuration in the System Settings, but it only has entries for 'Open with File Manager'. I've looked at the help, but it doesn't give me anything further than what I can deduce by looking around myself - specifically, I'm not sure how I would go about configuring an entry to play DVDs.

I've googled this, but I've not found anyone seeming to have the same issue.

Is there any way I can install a more complete set of default actions, or restore the actions from my previous Plasma 4 installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Long**

Solid Actions aka KDE4 vs KF5: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?68016-Open-with-VLC&p=371184&viewfull=1#post371184

**Short**

Copy /usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/ to ~/.local/share/solid/actions/

[image]

Run:

```
kbuildsycoca5 --noincremental
```

Reboot.

Use.

[image]

Comment: Very to the point, but does exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that, if you subsequently install any applications which add device notifier actions, they'll still appear in the old location so will need to be copied over as well.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to copy the contents of `/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/` to `/usr/share/solid/action` instead then issuing the command :

```
kbuildsycoca5 --noincremental
```

Once this is done, go to system settings and look into the device actions.  Doing it this way makes a reboot or logout/login unnecessary.

Comment: BTW.  This also works in Jonathan Riddle's KDE Neon distribution of linux as well since it's based on Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: quick note: KDE Neon is NOT based on Kubuntu it is based on Ubuntu. In fact, KDE Neon's page explains there is a lot of compatibility issues between Neon and Kubuntu. https://neon.kde.org/faq